# Play 2 morphia plugin - NoSuchMethodError: MorphiaLoggerFactory.reset()

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, morphia

I'm trying to use the MorphiaPlugin (https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin). On initialization, MorphiaPlugin tries to do this (line 45):

```
MorphiaLoggerFactory.reset();
```

Which raised the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.code.morphia.logging.MorphiaLoggerFactory.reset()V
 leodagdag.play2morphia.MorphiaPlugin.onStart(MorphiaPlugin.java:45)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:60)
 scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:60)
```

The plugin is linking against Morphia-1.00-snapshot (verified with play dependencies) which has the reset method. Anyone has any idea why it's not finding the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an idiot, the reason was because I had morphia-0.99 lying in lib/ which overrode the one from the plugin.

For those of you having classpath trouble, the following command is very handy:

```
play classpath
```